# vue.js computed for element of object

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object

```
Vue.component ('app-hous', {
        data: function () {
            return {
       message: 'Hello world, hello',
                houses: [
                    {name: "HILL8"},
                    {name: "HILL12"},                   
                ]
            }
        },
        computed: { 
            showMess () {
                return 'Get presentation ' +  this.hous.name
            },
        },
        template:   `
    <div><div class="houses" v-for="hous in houses">            
            <div class="plan">
               <div>{{ hous.name }} </div>            
               <div>{{ showMess }} </div>                             
            </div>
        </div></div>`
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#app', 
        data: {
            styleCSS: "",
            value: 1,       
        },      
    });
```

I need to compute element of object `houses`. But I run it before `v-for="hous in houses"`, so I can not get showMess. How I can fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/p43o8d69/

Comment: In simple words I would say think of a computed property as something that you already have, and you just want to represent it on the Front-end. In your example you don't have the value of this.hous.name in your data. It's just something you are showing in the v-for loop. 
To solve this you need a to pass a value from the v-for loop into a method

https://jsfiddle.net/oc8eu1r6/10/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a computed variable in this scenario.

Just use a method:

```
methods: {
    showMess(houseName) {
        return 'Get presentation ' +  houseName;
    }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
template: `
    <div><div class="houses" v-for="hous in houses">            
        <div class="plan">
            <div>{{ hous.name }} </div>            
               <div>{{ showMess(hous.name) }} </div>                             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`
```

Computed properties are meant to apply simple operations on your variables. But, in your case, the `hous` variable is not directly on data, it's an element of `houses` from the data.

Here is an example of a computed property that would accomplish the same thing, but I still suggest you to use the method example from above:

```
computed: {
    messByHouseName() {
        const messByHouseName = {};
        for (const house of this.houses) {
            messByHouseName[house.name] = `Get presentation ${house.name}`;
        }
        return messByHouseName;
    }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
template: `
    <div><div class="houses" v-for="hous in houses">            
        <div class="plan">
            <div>{{ hous.name }} </div>            
               <div>{{ messByHouseName[hous.name] }} </div>                             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`
```

Answer (score 1):

The computed property will not automatically loop over your houses. You have two ways to accomplish this. Either you can create a method (described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67773527/11011360) or create a computed property with the desired output (Edit: Catalin Hoha shows also a way to achieve this with a computed property but the approach is different):

```
convertedHouses() {
  const converted = houses.map(hous => {
    return {
      ...hous, // or you could write "name: hous.name" instead
      message: 'Get presentation ' + hous.name
    }
  });
  return converted;
}
```

And access the computed property like that in your template:

```
template: `
    <div class="houses" v-for="hous in convertedHouses">            
        <div class="plan">
            <div>{{ hous.name }} </div>            
            <div>{{ hous.message }} </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
`
```